# Invoke method of python class from groovy script

Tags: python, bash, groovy

I want to execute a method of my python class from groovy script.
This method have two parameter.

When i execute this command from terminal: 
python -c 'import Myclass; Myclass.method("param1","param2")' it is working.

I use this groovy script code :

```
def cmd = "cd /path/to/the/folder && python -c 'import Myclass; Myclass.method(param1,param2)'"
def proc = ["/bin/sh", "-c", cmd].execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "return code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```

When i want to do the same in the groovy script i have error with the parameter : NameError: name 'param1' is not defined.

Do you have any idea why ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you executed the script in the terminal, you used the **string literals `"param1", "param2"`** ,  not the undefined **variables `param1, param2`**. Since you have already used both single and double quotes, you should escape the double quotes with a backslash:

```
def cmd = "cd /path && python -c 'import Myclass; Myclass.method(\"param1\", \"param2\")'"
```

or, just use the triple quotes:

```
def cmd = '''cd /path && python -c 'import Myclass; Myclass.method("param1", "param2")' '''
```

Comment: I have this code in groovy script:

script = '''
def val1 = 'val1'
def val2 = 'val2'
def cmd = """
cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${param1}\",\"${param2}\")'
"""
some code
''';

I want to use parameter outside the script :

def val1 = 'val1'
def val2 = 'val2'
script = '''
def cmd = """
cd /path/to/my/folder && python -c 'import MyClass; MyClass.my_method(\"${param1}\",\"${param2}\")'
"""
some code
''';

I try to combine simple and double triple quote but it is not working, do you have any idea how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: @DavidBellerose So what is param1? You have only defined val1 or val2.