# Invoking a python script method from Groovy

Tags: python, groovy

Referring to this [Invoke method of python class from groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338619/invoke-method-of-python-class-from-groovy-script/62660841#62660841)

I have same scenario here, the command is running perfectly fine from the terminal but when running in groovy it throws Java.IO.Exception as it couldn't find the file path. Any idea on what I might be missing?

```
def cmd = "cd C:\\Users\\Desktop\\REG && python -c 'import reg; reg.method(\"param1\", \"param2\")'"
```

Where REG folder has reg.py script.

```
Error: Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: 1 - Did you try what was shown in the accepted answer and did that not work? 2 - Update your question with a code example, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Which file-path? Please add the code you have tried and the errors you got.

Comment: probably you are missing the file path? ;-)

Comment: The file path was correct, updated the post with error and script